# NSMatrix delegate

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmatrix

I have an NSMatrix in my code, specifically radio buttons. I would like to create a delegate to post a message when the radio button selection is changed.

Which delegate do I have to use? I have tried the textDidChange Method without any success.. obviously, I have used the [radioButtons setDelegate:self] at the initialization stage of the application.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSMatrix` is a subclass of `NSControl`, so you can use the same target-action paradigm as with any other `NSControl` such as a push button.

You can set the target and action on the `NSMatrix` using interface builder (control drag from the matrix to a class) or in code with `setTarget:` and `setAction:`. Then, when a cell in the matrix (here, a radio button) is selected, the action method is called, and you can query which radio button was selected with the `selectedCell` method.

See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Button/Articles/QueryMatrixButtons.html

Comment: I have created an IBAction and am trying to connect the IBAction method with the radio buttons. However, no connection is being made. Any idea how I can make the connection? Thanks.

Comment: You should be able to control drag from the matrix of radio buttons to your class with the IBAction. If that doesn't work, you can also find the `NSMatrix` in the sidebar (probably labeled "Matrix") and control drag from that text to your class. Also, make sure the button cells do not have connections set; otherwise, those actions will override the containing `NSMatrix` action.